# Compiler error: "Missing $ inserted"

Tags: equations

I have got the following equation in Latex. During compilation, the compiler complains about "Missing $ inserted". Unfortunately I am not able to find any error. Any ideas?

```
\begin{dmath} \frac{d^2\boldsymbol{cv}(\boldsymbol{x})}{dt^2}=\frac{d}{dt} \left \{ \frac{d\boldsymbol{cv}(\boldsymbol{x})}{dt} \right \}=\frac{d}{dt} \left \[ N(\boldsymbol{\theta})\boldsymbol{\omega}+nM(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \right \]=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left \[ N(\boldsymbol{\theta})\boldsymbol{\omega}+nM(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \right \]\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left \[ N(\boldsymbol{\theta})\boldsymbol{\omega}+nM(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \right \]\left \{ \begin{bmatrix}
N(\boldsymbol{\theta})\boldsymbol{\omega}+nM(\boldsymbol{\theta})\\ 
-J^{-1}\boldsymbol{\omega }\times J \boldsymbol{\omega}
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3 \times 3}\\ 
J^{-1} & J^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{T}_d \\ \boldsymbol{T }_c\end{bmatrix} \right \}=
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left \[ N(\boldsymbol{\theta})\boldsymbol{\omega}+nM(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \right \]\left \{ \begin{bmatrix}
N(\boldsymbol{\theta})\boldsymbol{\omega}+nM(\boldsymbol{\theta})\\ 
-J^{-1}\boldsymbol{\omega }\times J \boldsymbol{\omega}
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3 \times 3}\\ 
J^{-1} & J^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{T}_d \\ \boldsymbol{T }_c\end{bmatrix} \right \}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left \[ N(\boldsymbol{\theta})\boldsymbol{\omega}+nM(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \right \] \begin{bmatrix}
N(\boldsymbol{\theta})\boldsymbol{\omega}+nM(\boldsymbol{\theta})\\ 
-J^{-1}\boldsymbol{\omega }\times J \boldsymbol{\omega}
\end{bmatrix}+\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left \[ N(\boldsymbol{\theta})\boldsymbol{\omega}+nM(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \right \] \begin{bmatrix}
0_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3 \times 3}\\ 
J^{-1} & J^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{T}_d \\ \boldsymbol{T }_c\end{bmatrix} \end{dmath}
```

Comment: this whole passage is math, and you don't show any "wrapper" that indicates its "mathness".  that could easily be the cause of the `$` error message, since `$...$` is the canonical way to identify a math passage.

Comment: Generally, it is always best if you create a minimal, compilable example (an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)), that shows the problem. That is, a document containing a `\documentclass`, all necessary packages (but no more), `document` environment and the shortest code that shows your problem. That makes it much easier for those trying to help, as we can just copy-paste the entire code and compile it, saves us having to figure out which packages etc. are required, and setting up a document with those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\[` and `\]` are delimiters for a displayed math environment, to write a bracket you just write `[` or `]`. Try replacing all your `\left\[` with `\left[` and `\right\]` with `\right]`. Having done that, and placed your snippet in an `equation` environment, it compiles fine here, though the equation is far too long for a page.